# What is the difference between e-resize and ew-resize cursor types?

Tags: html, css

What is difference between these cursor types ? 
I see the same cursor for all 3 in Chrome/ windows

```css
.e-resize {cursor: e-resize;}
.ew-resize {cursor: ew-resize;}
.w-resize {cursor: w-resize;}
```

```html
<p>Mouse over the words to change the mouse cursor.</p>


<p class="e-resize">e-resize</p>
<p class="ew-resize">ew-resize</p>
<p class="w-resize">w-resize</p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: So what is the answer they all are same ?

Comment: @dota2pro if they are the same that does not means that the cool new browser you'll build *tomorrow* will not implement a different icon design to differentiate the two in a nice UX way - if you get rid of the OS default ones beforehand.

Comment: After the edit, it shows that you ran it. The line "I see the same cursor for all 3 in Chrome/ windows" now says why you are asking. ;) Answer is, get a better OS. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They provide the cursor that indicates if the content can be resized in the east, west or both directions.

[image: Animation showing the changing arrows]

Depending on your operating system, desktop environment, and theme: These cursors may or may not be different from each other:

**Windows 10:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those cursors are meant to represent resizing in their respective directions. The ew-resize cursor represents bidirectional resizing. Some operating systems such as Windows use the same double-headed horizontal arrow to represent all three cursors, though. macOS and many GNOME-based Linux desktops have single-headed arrows for the e-resize and w-resize cursors.

Answer (score -1):

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

> Some edge is to be moved. For example, the se-resize cursor is used when the movement starts from the south-east corner of the box.

So, east will resize to the right, while east-west will resize both directions.